# MySQL replication not syncing properly

Tags: mysql, replication

I have 2 mysql servers with circular replication set up between them. Doing a slave status check on both servers shows everything is OK. However, when an update on a table on server1 is done, server2 does not sync immediately. Sometimes it will sync after a few minutes. Sometimes it will only sync after mysqld on server2 is restarted.

I have

> innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1

and

> sync_binlog = 1

in my my.cnf files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sync-binlog` may be the prime suspect.

[MySQL Documntation on sync-binlog says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_sync_binlog)

> A value of 1 is the safest choice because in the event of a crash you lose at most one statement or transaction from the binary log. However, it is also the slowest choice (unless the disk has a battery-backed cache, which makes synchronization very fast).

I would check your disk controller battery on the Master

I would also recommend using

```
[mysqld]
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

I wrote about `innodb_flush_method` in the [**DBA StackExchange**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1575/877)

Comment: The server is a virtual CentOS server sitting on a Windows Server 2008 host. So I'm not sure how the virtual disk will behave in the event of a powerdown.